# SonarQube: Can't Create Technical User

Tags: authentication, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

SonarQube v5.2

I am trying to create a technical user (one that is authenticated locally and not against our LDAP).  I have added a user name to the conf/sonar.properties  file and restarted SonarQube. But, when I log in (as an administrator), the new user doesn't show up in the Administration | Security | Users list.  We have two previously defined technical users (including admin) which do show up.

The admin guide doesn't say much http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Authentication.

Is there another step needed to create a technical user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually create the user in SonarQube, it won't be automatically at startup.

Note that the SonarQube version you're using is no more supported, you should migrate to the latest LTS version 5.6.X => local users (previously known as technical users) are better managed :
- No more need to update sonar.properties
- You just have to create a user from the web server, this user will automatically be considered as a local user.

I've updated http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication in order to remove the "Technical" word.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "authenticate a first time with the local account"? How do I set the password to authenticate with?  Updating SonarQube is on the to-do list...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong : you need to manually create the user in SonarQube, it won't be automatically created at statup. I've updated my anser